# Hold large number in Python Variable

Tags: python

I am looking to do some basic math in python. However, I am dealing with numbers such as
`0.0000000001` and `-0.00000000001`

Are there any variables that can hold 10 decimal places with negative and positive numbers?

If not, I could multiply by `100000000000` and make it one, what is the best variable to hold numbers between `-100000000000` and `100000000000`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('0.0000000001')
y = Decimal('-0.00000000001')
```

Comment: Thanks Haidro, knew it would be something simple.